# How to build project from another project in TeamCity?

Tags: build, dependencies, continuous-integration, teamcity, share

Suppose we have a build project which takes a list member as a parameter.

Can I make another build which could run the first project with all parameters from list sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to reliably trigger multiple builds of type A based on a list you pass to build B.

What you could do is have B parse the list (using powershell or whatever else custom program you want to use) and then use the [TeamCity REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API) to trigger builds of type A with the right parameters, the [syntax described here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP) would apply to this:

> To trigger a build with custom parameters (system properties and
>   environment variables), use:
>
> [http://testuser:testpassword@teamcity.jetbrains.com/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=bt10&name=](http://testuser%3atestpassword@teamcity.jetbrains.com/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=bt10&name=)&value=&name=&value=

This allows you to pass the parameters you need for each build.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about it already. It seems that this the only way.